# IntelliSense code completion doesn't work with TypeScript enum values in VsCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

In my React TypeScript project, I created an `enum`:

```
export enum Example {
  NameOne = 'bad_name_one',
  NameTwo = 'bad_name_two',
}
```

Then I created this `type`:

```
export type CurrentExample = Example.NameOne | Example.NameTwo;
```

Now when I use type `CurrentExample`, I was expecting I get IntelliSense code completion in VsCode:

```
if (currentExample === '// Here I expect to get IntelliSense') {
  // do something
}
```

If I use just strings instead of the enum values it works just fine:

```
export type CurrentExample = 'bad_name_one' | 'bad_name_two';
```

Why is this and how should I use it in this case?

Comment: [Might be a workaround?](https://tsplay.dev/mq3PQw) Enums are a bit finicky in TypeScript.

Comment: but... why would you write the string literal when you could write `Example.<something>`? VS Code will even suggest for you if you don't write the quotes that you use the enum. This seems like subverting yourself (you defined the enum- why not use it?).